# chef cookbook not starting the service in bootstrap

Tags: chef-infra, knife, cookbook

I am trying to install a binary and start the service. When I try to do that while I bootstrap the node, it just install the binary and never start the service. Any idea?

```
bash "install_package" do
        cwd "/tmp/abcd"
        user "root"
        code <<-EOH
        sudo ./somefile -i -key=#{node[:abcd][:key]} -f
        EOH
        #not_if{ ::File.exists?("file it creates") }
        creates "/etc/init.d/someservce"
        action :run
        notifies :start, "service[someservce]", :immediately
do
```

My bin file accepts -i and key and get installed. But the service is not starting while boostrap...Even I tried a separate service resource to start the service it is not starting. Any idea?

Comment: Incognito: Thanks for the edit.

Comment: Actually my install bin file try to start the service. Does it affect anyway?

Comment: Does `/etc/init.d/someservice` exist?